# Sails JS Configured Route in Routes JS returns Not Found

Tags: node.js, express, routes, sails.js, sails-postgresql

I am using Sails JS, PostgreSQL stack.

I want to pass two ids as parameters at the end of a url as below:

> /getLocation/cc/re

Where 'cc' is a two letter country code e.g US and 're' is a an autocomplete query for a region of the country referred to in 'cc'

While using only cc works , adding the extra parameter results in a 'Not Found' page.

Here is the 'config/routes':

```
'get /location/getRegion/:cc/:re': 'LocationController.getRegion'
```

Pointing to say:

> 'localhost/location/getRegion/us/or'

results in a 404.

While:

> 'localhost/location/getRegion/us'

Works but obviously this outputs all regions/states in the us. The second parameter is supposed to filter this result further using 'contains'

Any ideas on how I can achieve the desired result using the two parameters?

Here is the

> getRegion

code in my

> LocationController

```
module.exports={
        getRegion:function(req, res, next){
        Regions.find({where:{country_code:req.param('cc')},region:{'contains':req.param('id')}},function selectRegions(err, regions){
            console.log(req.param('cc'))
            if(err) return next(err);
            if(!regions) return next();
            console.log(regions)
            res.json(regions)
        })
    }   
}
```

Comment: Works for me with a simple handler...can you post the `getRegion` code?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller code is a good demonstration of why we discourage using `next` in Sails controller actions: it can make things difficult to debug.  In your case, you've got the following in your `find` criteria:

```
region:{'contains':req.param('id')}
```

where you probably meant `req.param('re')`, since your route doesn't provide an `id` parameter.  Thus the query will always return no results, and you end up calling `next()`, which returns control to the Sails router which doesn't match any other routes and bingo, 404.  If you changed this:

```
if(!regions) return next();
```

to

```
if(!regions) return res.notFound();
```

it would have the same effect, but you'd probably have caught on sooner what was going on.